# How to print right justify string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that print the tree right justified. Here's my code:

```
height = int(input("Enter height of a tree: "))
for a in range(height + 1):
    for b in range(a):
        print("*", end="")  
    print()
for c in reversed(range(a)):
    for d in range(c):
        print("*", end="")
    print()
```

But currently it print the left justified tree. I want to justify the strings to right.

So instead of looking like this:
For instance, input = 2

```
*
**
*
```

Would look like that:

```
  *
 **
  *
```

Can't figure out the proper logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [`str.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) to right justify your string. For example

```
>>> '*'.rjust(5)
'    *'
```

Using this, you may create your function as:

```
def print_tree(height):
    half_height = int((height+1)/2)
    for i in range(1, height+1):
        if i <= half_height:
            print(('*'*i).rjust(half_height))
        else:
            print(('*'*(height-i+1)).rjust(half_height))
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> print_tree(5)
  *
 **
***
 **
  *
>>> print_tree(4)
 *
**
**
 *
>>> print_tree(3)
 *
**
 *
```

Comment: Right, but don't really know how to use it with the for loop. The program prints out one  "*" at a time.